# Erase Changes Upon Reboot?

Tags: windows, redirection, norton-goback, disk-protection

I recall Norton having an application that creates a set starting point, and no matter what I install, once I restart the computer it will return to that set point.

I have also seen this on college computers, no matter what I added once I restarted the computer, it would be erased. What is the name of this product? I want to to install it for a novice-computer-user who keeps getting viruses.

Answer (score 2):

i think that this might be what you are looking for. [Microsoft Steady State](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D077A52D-93E9-4B02-BD95-9D770CCDB431&displaylang=en)  This program allows you to control what the user has access to, what they can do, and also every restart erases all data they created on the pc

Comment: thanks but is there another one by norton? this person might have windows 7 and i dont think steady state is compatible with it

Answer (score 2):

[DeepFreeze](http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/DeepFreezeCorporate.aspx) is what I use to use and works great but there is also [Windows SteadyState](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d077a52d-93e9-4b02-bd95-9d770ccdb431&displaylang=en) which seems to be going away if you want to look into that. Norton had [GoBack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoBack) which has been replaced with [Norton Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost). That should get you on the right track.

Comment: yea norton goback that is what i was looking for thanks! i'll also try the others hopefully it works on windows 7 thanks!